# in 3 months, for 3 months, for the last 3 months

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Are the meanings of these three sentences different?

1. I won’t be surprised if my electricity is cut off. I haven’t paid the bill in three months.
2. I won’t be surprised if my electricity is cut off. I haven’t paid the bill for three months.
3. I won’t be surprised if my electricity is cut off. I haven’t paid the bill for the last three months.

Comment: No. (1) looks like American usage to me, (2) is British usage and (3) spells it out more precisely.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you very much.

Comment: Undeniably, there ***are*** several possible meanings, and ***none*** of the above unambiguously admit of only a single meaning. If being precise is important to the speaker he probably needs to use a *lot* more words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ***in** [period of time]* form (which is now common, whereas a century ago it was almost always ***for***) is significantly more likely when the "period of time" is just ***years, months, weeks,...***

As [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seen%20him%20in%20years%2Cseen%20him%20for%20years%2C%28%28seen%20him%20in%20two%20years%29*4%29%2C%28%28seen%20him%20for%20two%20years%29*4%29&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) shows, although ***in years*** is now significantly more common than semantically equivalent ***for years***, when the period is *quantified* as, say, ***two** years*, the ***for*** version is still *slightly* more common. We can reasonably expect ***in*** to win out more decisively in future, but I'm never gonna like *I haven't paid my bill **in the last three months***.

[image]

Note that I multiplied the occurrence counts for the "quantified" versions by 4, so they'd fit on the same chart (we're only interested in the *ratio* there, not the absolute values).

---

As regards *meaning*, all of OP's alternatives are equivalent. They're all "acceptable", but the first one is the most natural version today.

Comment: I'm, obviously behind the times. If you select for British English in that Ngrams search, _for_ is more common but _in_ is rapidly catching up with it.

Comment: I usually make a point of checking NGrams for any significant US/UK usage difference if I have even a *vague* sense that there might be one. It just never occurred to me on this one - but having just compared the two charts, I think it's basically just that the meteoric ascendance of ***in*** displacing ***for*** happened about half a century ago in AmE, but it was a couple of decades later in BrE.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Worth noting: The three options given in the question don’t _necessarily_ mean the same thing. The first two are almost certainly equivalent, meaning that I receive a bill each month, but for the past three months, I haven’t paid (I now have three outstanding bills); but the third can **also** mean that I pay quarterly, so I receive one bill every three months, but I haven’t paid the one covering the past three months (I have one outstanding bill).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Sorry, but I can't agree. All versions are ambiguous, and much depends on how we *expect* the bills to be raised (monthly, quarterly, annually,...). But I can easily convince myself #1 is more likely in the sense of *I'm billed monthly, but haven't paid the last three bills*, whereas #2 might mean *I'm billed annually, but the last bill was three months ago and I still haven't paid it*. And #3 could carry the first of those senses, OR it might mean *I'm billed quarterly, but haven't paid the latest bill* (perhaps only received fairly recently).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, you’re right, #2 might mean that as well, didn’t think of that option. I would find #1 odd in the annual-but-not-paid-yet sense, but not #2. Though of course, there’s nothing wrong with “I got the bill in December, but I haven’t paid it in the three months since then”…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I think the main takeaway here should be that none of the examples even come *close* to being unambiguous. Learners often take it for granted that if there are two/three ways of saying something, and two/three likely possible interpretations, it must be the case that each alternative phrasing carries only one of the possible meanings. But in this case it's effectively "ambiguities all the way down".

Answer (score 4):

In this context, where the period is in the past, there is no significant difference in meaning. All three quoted sentences have the same meaning. The answer by Fumblefingers and the comments by Kate Bunting clarify relative frequency of usage.

But when the period is in the future, the two forms have significantly different meanings.

> - (1) The rental will be available **in** three months.
> - (2) The rental will be available **for** three months.

Sentence (1) means that the rental will be available starting three months in the future. But (2) means that the rental will only be available for a period **of** three months, probably starting right away, unless a further statement clarifies this. In this context the different prepositions carry different meanings.

In the context of the duration of an event, only some forms are acceptable.

> - (3) He was able to get the job done **in** two weeks.
> - (4) He was able to get the job done **for** two weeks.

Here sentence (3) mans that the job was accomplished within a time span of two weeks. But (4) has a very different meaning (which I missed, thanks to John Bollinger  for pointing it out). It means that he was able to perform the job for a period of two weeks, but not after that.

So the difference, if an, between "*in {period of time}*" and  "*for {period of time}*" depends on the semantic context, that is, on the *meaning* of the text of which it is a part.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: (4) is perfectly valid in standard English, but it means something different than (3).  Consider this augmentation: "He was able to get the job done for two weeks, then he burned out."  The "in" form implies completion, as you say.  The "for" form conveys duration but not (necessarily) completion.  Consider also "He was able to backpack in Europe for two weeks", which has the same form.

Comment: @John Bollinger
 You have a point. I will edit my answer to take account of it.

Comment: @John’s interpretation didn’t occur to me either because _get the job done_ so strongly implies completion that it almost rules out (4) as being valid. If you modify it to _do the job_, it becomes much clearer: “He was able to do the job in two weeks” (completion) vs “He was able to do the job for two weeks [before burning out/quitting in disgust/etc.]” (non-completion).

Answer (score 0):

They have essentially the same meaning, although I'd say the first is the most unclear and the last is the clearest, if you want your meaning to be very explicit.

"In three months" can refer to either the past or the future, so there is some potential room for confusion if the rest of the context might lead someone to think you were talking about the future, whereas the last two obviously refer to the past. Although the sentence you have given in your example should make it fairly clear you're talking about the past so it's unlikely to confuse anybody.

When referring to the past, "in" is most commonly used in a more vague way, i.e. "I haven’t paid the bill in months", which would, again, be similar in meaning to the examples you've given but is more vague about exactly how many months.

Comment: Thank you very much.